# Can not repeat a part of code in lua using for loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, lua

I have this table called rs which contains 7(say n) strings.
For #rs, I want OBX segment to iterate over it as follows:

```
for i=1, #rs, 1 do
Msg.OBX[5][1] = rs[i]
end
```

As my output, I want:

```
Msg.OBX[5][1] = first string
Msg.OBX[5][1] = second string
Msg.OBX[5][1] = third string
```

repeated #rs times

But what I get from above code is only one segment corresponding to the last string i.e If i had 7 strings in rs, I get only seventh string and not all seven strings.

How can I fix this?

Comment: How can you store 7 **different** values to a single space?

Comment: Actually these segments are something what is difficult to explain here, not related to programming , but all I want is OBX to repeat n times and that is where I want help

Comment: What do you mean by "but all I want is OBX to repeat n times", perhaps you can give an example of rs table looks like, and what you want Msg.OBX to be, using brackets rather than indices because as mentioned by @hjpotter92 the way you have it listed there does not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get that output, unless you have a print statement. Do `Msg.OBX[5][i] = rs[i]` instead. But then you will have

```
Msg.OBX[5][1] = first string
Msg.OBX[5][2] = second string
Msg.OBX[5][3] = third string
...
```

which is probably what you are really after. If this still doesn't work, try

```
Msg.OBX[5][1] = {}
for i=1, #rs do
    table.insert(Msg.OBX[5][1], rs[i])
end
```

If you still don't get all strings from `rs` into OBX, then maybe your `rs` table has wholes, so try this:

```
for i,v in ipairs(rs) do print(i,v) end
```

If this doesn't print the following then rs has holes or is not array so you can't use `#`:

```
1      first string
2      second string
...
7      seventh string
```

Comment: I have tried using Msg.OBX[i] and I do not have any problem with that either but even that is not working and all it results in Msg.OBX[7] = seventh string, That's all I am getting